# Google Chrome won't open

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

I can't open Google Chrome on an Acer laptop with Windows 10 installed. There was a strange problem first whereas it was set with compatability mode for Vista, but I removed that setting. Now what happens is that I double tap it, but it only requests permission to perform changes on the PC and doesn't open. The icon has an admin-shield icon on it. I've tried to reinstall it, but the installer is stuck on the downloading screen. The standalone installer, however, works - but with the same end result.

**Any idea what could be the cause?**

Comment: Remove Chrome and Then Restart then try and install again.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to delete your profile folder (backup bookmarks first).
Just delete "\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\" (default contains your profile data) Good luck!
Found here:
[Website with chrome wont open fixes](http://chrome.wont-open.com/Itself/)